# D3DCOMPILER_43.dll contains an error

Tags: technical-issues

Whilst trying to run Dirt 3 or Dragon age 2, I get the following error message:

'D3DCOMPILER_43.dll is either not designed to run on windows or it contains an error'

I'm running an ATI 6970 card on Win7 x64, I've reinstalled the drivers for the video card, I've downloaded the Direct X driver dist and manually replaced that file with the latest.
I've run 'sfc /scannow' that I found on one forum as a suggestion, but to no avail - it still errors out. Does anyone have any ideas what else it could be?

Answer (score 3):

First of all I suggest you to check the source that you used to install the game. Is it a retail box copy? Does it come from digital services like Origin or Steam?

In case of digital delivery try use game cache verification (Steam has this function, I don't know the other services) and then try to uninstall the game and reinstall it, in any case.

If the problem is not solved could be that you miss an important system update. It seems that the DLL D3DCOMPILER_43.dll has been released in [June 2010 DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937789). You can try to install this [DirectX 11 Technology Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17431) and see if it fixes the problem.